# Python ElementTree - Search children/grandchildren in poorly written XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse through a poorly coded XML and output the Node Name and content of a tag (only if it exists), and only if string name=content > 30 day(s).

Thus far I can search the children elements using ElementTree, but I need help with the poorly nested info.  I can't change the XML because it's a vendor provided report.  I'm a complete newbie, so please coach me on what I need to do or provide for better help.  Thanks in advance.

Example File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportSection>
    <ReportHead>
        <Criteria>
            <HeadStuff value=Dont Care>
            </HeadStuff>
        </Criteria>
    </ReportHead>
    <ReportBody>
        <ReportSection name="UpTime" category="rule">
            <ReportSection name="NodeName.domain.net" category="node">
                <String name="node">NodeName.domain.net</String>
                <String name="typeName">Windows Server</String>
                <OID>-1y2p0ij32e8c8:-1y2p0idhghwg6</OID>
                <ReportSection name="UpTime" category="element">
                    <ReportSection name="2015-09-20 18:50:10.0" category="version">
                        <String name="version">UpTime</String>
                        <OID>-1y2p0ij32e8cj:-1y2p0ibspofhp</OID>
                        <Integer name="changeType">2</Integer>
                        <String name="changeTypeName">Modified</String>
                        <Timestamp name="changeTime" displayvalue="9/20/15 6:50 PM">1442793010000</Timestamp>
                        <ReportSection name="versionContent" category="versionContent">
                            <String name="content">12 day(s), 7 hour(s), 33 minute(s), 8 second(s)</String>
                            <String name="content"></String>
                        </ReportSection>
                    </ReportSection>
                </ReportSection>
            </ReportSection>
        </ReportSection>
    </ReportBody>
</ReportSection>
```

Comment: What is your desired result? Have you tried anything? Thanks..

Comment: I want to return the "node" value "NodeName.domain.net", and the content of "12 day(s)" if the value is greater than 30.                           ## Import the parser
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

## Set the xml file and parse it
root = et.parse('c:\\temp\\scans\\report.xml')

for Sec1 in root.iter():
 Sec1Name = Sec1.attrib.get('name')
 print (Sec1Name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to locate the `content` node, extract how many days are there, then check the value if needed, and locate the node name. Example (using [`lxml.etree`](http://lxml.de/)):

```
import re

from lxml import etree

pattern = re.compile(r"^(\d+) day\(s\)")

data = """your XML here"""
tree = etree.fromstring(data)

content = tree.findtext(".//String[@name='content']")
if content:
    match = pattern.search(content)
    if match:
        days = int(match.group(1))

        # TODO: check the days if needed

        node = tree.findtext(".//String[@name='node']")

        print node, days
```

Prints:

```
NodeName.domain.net 12
```

Comment: Will this work if the example above repeats several thousand times?  node1, node2, node3 changes in the depth of the xml.

Comment: @KFrizz not in this state. You would basically need to iterate over `ReportSection` nodes and make the code context-specific to every `ReportSection` in the loop. You should've stated it in the question. I think the answer is a good start for you and you'll improve it to support multiple `ReportSection` nodes.